# ant scp failure

Tags: java, ant, scp

This is how I am trying to scp to a remote machine, I am trying to copy whole directory to destination directory.

```
<target name="report-test-results" depends="run-junit-tests">
    <scp todir="root:somepassword@192.168.8.120:/home/hrishikesh/webui-test-results/">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/test-results"/>
    </scp>
</target>
```

I am getting following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\hrishikesh\workspace\selenium4j\build.xml:122: Problem: failed to create task or type scp
Cause: Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/Logger
       It is not enough to have Ant's optional JARs
       you need the JAR files that the optional tasks depend upon.
       Ant's optional task dependencies are listed in the manual.
Action: Determine what extra JAR files are needed, and place them in one of:
        -ANT_HOME\lib
        -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.

This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error output is pretty clear on how to fix this:

```
Action: Determine what extra JAR files are needed, and place them in one of:
    -ANT_HOME\lib
    -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs
```

In your case you're missing the jsch JAR file, which can be downloaded from the [JSch site](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Comment: bang on target...it clearly said not to panic but I did. Anyway, my problem is solved, thanks. Thanks to krock as well.

Comment: On Debian it is enough to install `libjsch-java` package.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the [library dependancies](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies) for the `scp` task.  You need to include [`jsch.jar`](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html) in your classpath.

Answer (score -2):

Add the [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) JAR file inside Eclipse - *Windows > Preferences > Ant > Classpath*.

You can get the [JAR file](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.jcraft%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsch%22) from the Maven Central Repository.